# PDFBox how to clone a page

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm working on a code which suppose to take a data to insert into a form and just fill the form with that data.

I'm trying to create a simple pdf multi-page document with the given data in it.

My problem is that my code works partially. I could run the code and generate a multi-page document 6 times in a row, but on the 7th attempt I would get an error like this:

```
java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.checkClosed(COSStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createOutputStream(COSStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createOutputStream(COSStream.java:186)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.writeToStream(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:641)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.setAppearanceContent(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:303)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.setAppearanceValue(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:170)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:263)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField.applyChange(PDTerminalField.java:228)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.setValue(PDTextField.java:218)
    at app.components.FieldPopulator.insertData(FieldPopulator.java:153)
    at app.components.FieldPopulator.populateGoodsFields(FieldPopulator.java:69)
    at app.Main.populateData(Main.java:55)
    at app.Main.main(Main.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:143)
Error: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?Document has been createdjava.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.checkClosed(COSStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createRawInputStream(COSStream.java:125)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1200)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.accept(COSStream.java:383)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject.accept(COSObject.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:522)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObjects(COSWriter.java:460)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteBody(COSWriter.java:444)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1096)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:419)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1254)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1232)
    at app.Main.saveDocument(Main.java:62)
    at app.Main.main(Main.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:143)
```

I would like to know why is this error keeps coming, or how could it be that the code works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is the main class(I removed irrelevent parts of the code):

```
package app;

import app.components.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by David on 11/01/2017.
 */
public class Main {

    private static FormMetaHolder metaHolder = new FormMetaHolder();

    private static HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    private static List<GoodObject> objects = new ArrayList();
    private static PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        initiateData(); // This method generates sample data. I removed it for simplicity
        initiatePdf();
        populateData();
        saveDocument();

        System.out.print("Document has been created");
    }

    public static void initiatePdf() {
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder();
        builder.setObjectsData(objects);

        document = builder.build();
    }

    public static void populateData() throws IOException {
        FieldPopulator populator = new FieldPopulator(document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(), metaHolder);

        populator.numberPages();
        populator.populateStaticFields(properties);
        populator.populateGoodsFields(objects);
    }

    public static void saveDocument() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Constants.Paths.RESULT_FILE);

            document.save(out);
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `build()` method from `DocumentBuilder` class. This is the 
which generates an empty, ready to be populated document based on how much data need to be inserted:

```
public PDDocument build() {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        try {
            int numPages = evaulator.getNumOfPages(objectsToInsert);

            // A FieldRenamer for renaming the DG fields sequentially
            FieldRenamer renamer = new FieldRenamer();

            PDResources res = new PDResources();

            // First one here is a list of the unique fields of the document
            List<PDField> parentFields = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
                try {
                    InputStream stream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(Constants.Paths.EMPTY_DOC);
                    templateDoc = new PDDocument().load(stream);

                    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = templateDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
                    PDAcroForm acroForm = catalog.getAcroForm();

                    if (i == 1)
                        res = acroForm.getDefaultResources();

                    // Renaming the PDFields
                    renamer.setAcroForm(acroForm);
                    renamer.renameFields(i * 10 + 1 - 10);

                    PDPage page = catalog.getPages().get(0);

                    // Iterating over the acro form to find new fields that are not
                    // In the main collection of fields - the parentFields object
                    // If a field is already inside the parentFields list, add new
                    // PDAnnotationWidget to that field, for visual representation
                    // In the new page
                    List<PDAnnotation> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (PDField field : acroForm.getFields()) {
                        boolean flag = true;
                        for (PDField parentField : parentFields) {
                            String currentFieldName = field.getFullyQualifiedName();
                            String parentFieldName = parentField.getFullyQualifiedName();

                            if (currentFieldName.equals(parentFieldName)) {
                                flag = false;

                                PDAnnotationWidget existWidget = parentField.getWidgets().get(0);
                                PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();

                                widget.setPage(page);
                                widget.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PARENT, parentField);
                                widget.setRectangle(existWidget.getRectangle());

                                parentField.getWidgets().add(widget);
                                widgets.add(widget);
                                page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (flag) {
                            parentFields.add(field);
                        }
                    }

                    document.addPage(page);

                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.print("Error: could not load the template file");
                }
            }

            PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);

            acroForm.setFields(parentFields);
            acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);

            document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Error: no data has been set to insert");
        }

        return document;
    }
```

Now, I think the problem lies with the way I'm dealing with the `PDField`s and their annotations inside the `build()` method, but I can't pinpoint the source of the problem.

Please help me with this guys, I've been struggling with this for some time and I just want to proceed with my project, knowing that this part of the program works perfectly.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Ok so the main cause of the problem is in the `build()` method inside the `DocumentBuilder` class. I will try to clarify a little bit about my code:

first, I create a new document which is intended to be the result document.

Next, I figure out using my Evalutor class how much pages are needed in order
to populate the data. Inside the `Evaluator` I perform certain calculations. A little note, I use the `FormMetaHolder` object which its job is to provide meta data about acro form fields, data such as field font, font size,
field width and field name. The field font variable holds a reference to
the actual PDFont object I took from the form resources.

Next, I loop over the number of pages and for each iteration I do the following:

.1. Create a new `PDDocument` from the template file and assign it to `templateDoc`

.2. Get the acro form from that document.
.2.1. If it's the first iteration, assign default
resources of the acro form to the `res` variable.

.3. Rename identical fields which I want to contain different values. Because the multi line feature in PDFBox is full of bugs, I divided certain fields of the same size into 10 smaller fields. Each small field like this is numbered. For Instance, if the big field is called "UN" then
all the smaller fields will be called UN1, UN2,
UN3...

Now, if I have a lot of data to insert, I want to be able to duplicate the template document with the only exception of renaming those smaller fields appropriatly. For example, if I need 2 pages to store the data that was 
provided by the user, I need 20 smaller fields, 10 for each page.
I need all the UNs field to be renamed like this:
UN1 - UN20

.4. After I rename all the smaller fields accordingly, I try to find new annotations for my list of parentFields. The reason I do that is because besides of the "smaller" fields, I also have static fields which don't change
across pages.

.5. After I find all the correct widgets, I add the current page to the result document and close the `InputStream` which was used to instantiate the `templateDoc` object.

After the for loop is over, I create a new `PDAcroForm` object with the result document as the argument. I set its fields to be
`parentFields` and set the default resources
to be the `res` object.

Finally, I set the document acro form to be the newly created acro form.

Comment: "I could run the code and generate a multi-page document 6 times in a row, but on the 7th attempt I would get an error like this" please clarify. Is it 7 times with the same document combination or with different ones? Is it 7 times running the whole program or only the segment? (the main part is static) Why are you generating PDDocument() objects only to overwrite them? I saw this at least twice. It isn't the cause of your problems but makes your code more difficult to read. I'm sure your IDE flags this. My guess is that it is related to closing templateDoc but I can't see where you close it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr *"My guess is that it is related to closing templateDoc but I can't see where you close it."* - My impression, too. Those instances go out of scope, so eventually garbage collection will take care of them. Which makes effects appear pseudo-random.

Comment: David, have you tried importing the page in question using `PDDocument.importPage()`? The method comment explains the difference to simply adding the page using `PDDocument.addPage()` and also contains a caveat.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr What I mean by 6 times is that the code can work a several attempts in a row, but could fail suddenly on the next attempt. I'm using one template which I work with. I generate templateDoc because I want to collect unique fields and add them to the parentFields list. I added some description on what I'm trying to do

Comment: @mkl I tried the `importPage()` method but with no success. I added some description on what I'm trying to do. Please take a look!

Comment: *I tried the `importPage()` method but with no success* - how exactly did you try? Your code should work if you initially import the page from the template doc, manipulate the imported page, and then add it to the target PDF. There have been some issues with the `importPage()` method in some PDFBox versions; thus, which PDFBox version do you use? That been said, it could also be a question of the availability of the default resources. Thus, in addition to using `importPage()` you may also have to copy the default resources once from the template to the target document.